# web installer has stopped working

Tags: windows-7, web-platform-installer

I have just downloaded and installed web platform installer on Windows 7 machine, and was trying to install Orchard CMS through it. It downloads the CMS from the internet, but when starting the installation it halts with the Windows error message "Web platform installer has stopped working". This is the text file I found in logs/webpi:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x86
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Wed, 06 Apr 2011 17:49:12 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "2c1614f082f4cb1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 279210300600000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2011 15:59:12 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\adeel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\903079739.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x86
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 203
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 15 Jun 2011 15:58:14 GMT
Location: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=98494c5839a59f4c85c4f583e23130c6&HASH=584c&LV=20116&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2011 15:59:13 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Orchard CMS (OrchardCMS) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'OrchardCMS'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'NETFramework4' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WindowsImagingComponent' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product WebMatrix_appdetect does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WDeployNoSMO' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'NETFramework20SP2' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WindowsInstaller31' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No SQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No MySQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://orchard.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?DownloadId=249650' to: C:\Users\adeel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4E19.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment; filename="Orchard.Web.1.2.41.zip"
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\adeel\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp4E19.tmp' to: C:\Users\adeel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\OrchardCMS\91C4DFE0C853C3961338BF24DF7A8655973E71F4\Orchard.Web.1.2.41.zip
```

I appreciate your help and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough free drive space to hold two copies of it?

I ask because the last line seems to indicate that it's last action was to copy from the cache to the WIP temporary install source location.

```
...tmp4E19.tmp' to: C:\Users\adeel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\OrchardCMS\91C4DFE0C853C3961338BF24DF7A8655973E71F4\Orchard.Web.1.2.41.zip
```

Comment: 18 gb free space in c:\ its been two days and i can't get it working

Comment: What happens if you try to navigate to that folder and open the Zip file manually?

Comment: it opens fine and contains folder named orchard and files install.sql and somemanifest files

Comment: Interesting, well at least the file seems to not be corrupt. You may want to check out Process Monitor and Process Explorer (both by MS and easily Googled/downloaded) and use them to try and determine what's trying to access what when the WIP interface becomes busy/unresponsive.